# Remnants from package installation

Tags: mac

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.1

I was trying to install the Tor browser, but instead I mistakenly installed some general Tor proxy or something, which didn't come in the form of a normal application.

Basically I first installed MacPorts and then I did `sudo port install tor` which didn't give me the Tor browser, but some other Tor thing (I think it's something that allows you to use Tor proxy with any application, but I don't need that.)

So anyway, that command installed a bunch of components that I don't want or need on my system. How can I purge all these components from my system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo port uninstall tor`.

To remove any inactive packages this might leave behind, run `sudo port uninstall inactive`.